# Zooming on objects from external SVG in d3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js, zooming

Need help with zooming on SVG objects. I have some external SVG (made in Inksape), it is quite big and I want to be able to zoom to some parts/objects of it with help of D3.js. But I can't understand how to make it, all examples about maps and canvas. Any suggestions how to make it, both zooming to object(BBox) and coordinates.

Here is some code, example.svg is bigger than 640x480. On pressing spacebar I need some transformation (translate/scale), which will show another part of example.svg:

```
var width = 640,
height = 400,
focused = false;

var pano = d3.select("div#pano");

d3.xml("data/example.svg", "image/svg+xml", function(xml) {
  var importedNode = document.importNode(xml.documentElement, true);
  d3.select("#pano").node().appendChild(importedNode);

  frames = d3.select("g#main");

  var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
      .translate([0, 0])
      .scale(1)
      .on("zoom", zoomed);

   pano.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "overlay")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .on("keydown", function() {
        if (d3.event.keyCode == 32) {
          this.call(zoom);
        }
      })

   function zoomed() {
      frames.attr("transform", "translate(" + [0, -400] + ")");
   }    
});
```

Comment: This is a very broad question and you haven't shown us what you have tried. I suggest that you have a look at the [zoom behavior](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior) in particular.

Comment: As you have explained it I don't think this is a job well suited for d3. It seems like this could be solved with svg transforms.

Comment: Yes, it can be solved with svg transform, but without smooth zooming and panning.